# Python, Inject code into module globals

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, module

I'm trying to bypass importing from a module, so in my `__init__.py` I can inject code like this:

```
globals().update(
    {
         "foo": lambda: print("Hello stackoverflow!")
    }
)
```

so if I do `import mymodule` I will be able to call `mymodule.foo`. That is a simple concept, useless for the purpose because you can actually just define `foo`.
So, the idea is to modify the `globals` module dictionary, so in case it doesn't find the function `foo` it will go wherever and I can inject the code, for that I tried:

```
from importer import load #a load function to search for the code
from functools import wraps

def global_get_wrapper(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args):
        module_name, default = args
        res = f(*args)
        if res is None:
            return load(module_name)
        return res
    return wrapper

globals().get = global_get_wrapper(globals().get) # trying to substitute get method
```

But it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object attribute 'get' is read-only
```

The other idea I had is to preload the available function, class, etc names into the module dictionary and lazily load them later.

I run out of ideas to accomplish this and I don't know if this is even possible.
Should I go for writing my own python importer? or is there any other possibility I could not think about?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its dificult to mess with globals: it is a strange thing `print(type(globals)) -> builtin_function_or_method`

Comment: It is unclear what you asking for.

Comment: @EthanFurman, would you help me reformulate the question? sometimes It may be difficult to explain ideas :/ There are 2 good answers that solved what I was looking for.

Comment: I'd be happy to, if I understood what you are asking for.  :(  Maybe some example code actually using this technique, not just sample code of the technique, would help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of hacking `globals()` it would be better to define `__getattr__` for your module as follows:

## module_name.py

```
foo = 'foo'

def bar():
    return 'bar'
```

## my_module.py

```
import sys

import module_name

class MyModule(object):
    def foobar(self):
        return 'foobar'

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(module_name, item)

sys.modules[__name__] = MyModule()
```

and then:

```
>>> import my_module
>>> my_module.foo
'foo'
>>> my_module.bar()
'bar'
>>> my_module.foobar()
'foobar'
```

Comment: You can do it in a single file. Just change `getattr(module_name, item)`
 to `globals()[item]`

Comment: @polvoazul Yes, this is also possible, but in my understanding OP wants to load implementations from third-party module in case they aren't found in his own, that's why there are 2 files in my answer.

Comment: @Vader, This did exactly what I needed, so instead of substitute the module dictionary i substitute the entire module for a custom loader class. thank you so much. great idea!

Answer (score 3):

[PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/), which targets Python 3.7, introduces `__getattr__` for modules. In the rationale it also describes workarounds for previous Python versions.

> It is sometimes convenient to customize or otherwise have control over access to module attributes. A typical example is managing deprecation warnings. Typical workarounds are assigning `__class__` of a module object to a custom subclass of `types.ModuleType` or replacing the `sys.modules` item with a custom wrapper instance. It would be convenient to simplify this procedure by recognizing `__getattr__` defined directly in a module that would act like a normal `__getattr__` method, except that it will be defined on module *instances*.

So your `mymodule` can look like:

```
foo = 'bar'

def __getattr__(name):
    print('load you custom module and return it')
```

Here's how it behaves:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.foo
'bar'
>>> mymodule.baz
load you custom module and return it
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand. Would this work for you?

```
try:
    mymodule.foo()
except:
    print("whatever you wanted to do")
```

Comment: thanks for the effort but no, it should be evaluated when the module is imported, so if `mymodule`doesnt contain a function foo it will go and sarch somewhere else, but it is `mymodule` actually what should handle that

Comment: Ok, I see you've got it answered